# Can PerfView be used for finding source of fragmentation

Tags: .net, large-object-heap, memory-fragmentation, perfview

I am finding PerfView to be very useful tool for determining root cause of various type of problems. However I am not sure if it can also be used to diagnose LOH fragmentation problem. I have collected a process memory snapshot using PerfView. In past for this process we have observed LOH fragmentation but back then I used to get the value from !heapstat command. Anyone knows if PerfView could help for determining:

1. How badly LOH is fragmented
2. What objects could be causing this fragmentation